# Parenthesis don't appear in beamer

Tags: beamer, equations, parentheses

I'd like to show parenthesis in equation environment for beamer presentation. I don't know because it not appear.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage[subnum]{cases}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{lmodern} % required to show the problem

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{} 
\newcommand{\bs}{\mathbf}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
\section{Introdução}
%\subsection{First Subsection}
\begin{frame}{Unified Particle Swarm Optimizer - UPSO}
    \justifying
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=red!75!black}
    \begin{block}{PSO tradicional}
        PSO tradicional foi proposto por Eberhart, R. C. and Kennedy, J. (1995) e apresenta as seguintes equações:
        \begin{equation*}
            \begin{aligned}
                v_{i+1} = \omega v_i + r_1c_1 (\bs{lbest_i} - \bs{x_i}) + r_2c_2 (\bs{gbest_i} - \bs{x_i})\\
                x_{i+1} = x_i + v_{i}\\
            \end{aligned}
        \end{equation*}

    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First: Which parantheses do not appear? Second: You  may change `\newcommand{\bs}{\mathbf}` to `\newcommand{\bs}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` [\bs and \mathbf are macros, which take an argument, and not switches].

Comment: In instance, `(\bs{lbest_i} - \bs{x_i})` these parentheses `(` and `)`.

Comment: This is a miracle. After running your mwe I really get these parentheses. You may have a look into the log-file: Are there any warnings regarding fonts?

Comment: Yes, I tried more once and they appeared. But in my real problem still don't appear.

Comment: The question is if they appear in the code that you provide here.

Comment: @ Jorge: Then you shall try to produce a mwe which really shows the problem, so that we can help you. Perhaps you will find the solution while preparing the mwe.

Comment: I removed the packages one to one and I found the problem: the package `lmodern`. I removed and it is working. Thank you! (Sorry by english)

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this: when adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` to the above code the parentheses in the equation disappear.

Answer (score 6):

When you change the order of the packages `lmodern` and `MnSymbol` to

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
```

than you get the parentheses again.